# Xdebug is not working in a Docker setup for a VSCode editor

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am setting up Xdebug in a Docket set up. I am using VSCode editor.

My VSCode source tree looks like this:
[image]

My Docker file looks like this:

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y iputils-ping && apt-get install -y vim 

RUN pecl install xdebug

RUN echo 'zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so' | tee /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" | tee -a /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_port=9000" | tee -a /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=1" | tee -a /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=0" | tee -a /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.idekey=VSCODE" | tee -a /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal" | tee -a /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

My compose file looks like as follows:

```
 php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9002:9000"
    networks:
      - laravelAdmin
    environment:
      PHP_EXTENSION_XDEBUG: 1
```

My launch.json file looks as follows:

```
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}",
                // "/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}/html",
                // "/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}/www",
                // "/src": "${workspaceRoot}/src"
                // "/src": "${workspaceRoot}"
            },
            "ignore": [
                "**/vendor/**/*.php"
            ],
            "log": true,
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

On debug, the breakpoint does not work.

Though if I remove the 'Ignore' section from the launch.json then it shows me the error from the vendor's folder but it does not break in my code.

Can you please help me find the issue here?

The xdebug log says.

```
   [14] Log opened at 2020-09-15 04:37:54
[14] I: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9000.
[14] I: Connected to client. :-)
[14] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="dbgp://stdin" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.3.20" protocol_version="1.0" appid="14" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="2.9.6"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2020 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[14] <- breakpoint_list -i 1
[14] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="1"></response>

[14] <- breakpoint_set -i 2 -t line -f file:///var/www/html/src/app/Http/Controllers/CreateUsers.php -n 16
[14] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="2" id="140001"></response>

[14] <- breakpoint_set -i 3 -t line -f file:///var/www/html/src/app/Http/Controllers/CreateUsers.php -n 27
[14] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="3" id="140002"></response>

[14] <- breakpoint_list -i 4
[14] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="4"><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///var/www/html/src/app/Http/Controllers/CreateUsers.php" lineno="16" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="140001"></breakpoint><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///var/www/html/src/app/Http/Controllers/CreateUsers.php" lineno="27" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="140002"></breakpoint></response>

[14] <- breakpoint_list -i 5
[14] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="5"><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///var/www/html/src/app/Http/Controllers/CreateUsers.php" lineno="16" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="140001"></breakpoint><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///var/www/html/src/app/Http/Controllers/CreateUsers.php" lineno="27" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="140002"></breakpoint></response>

[14] <- breakpoint_set -i 6 -t exception -x *
[14] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="6" id="140003"></response>

[14] <- run -i 7
[14] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="7" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[14] <- stop -i 8
[14] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stop" transaction_id="8" status="stopped" reason="ok"></response>

[14] Log closed at 2020-09-15 04:37:5
```

4

Comment: 1) What is your host OS (where Docker/VSCode is running)? It's important (as `host.docker.internal` is not available on Linux (Docker issue) and you need to manually find out the right IP address of your host OS). 2) Enable and collect Xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug session: it will tell where it tries to connect (if it does). It's possible that Xdebug collides with php-fpm (that you may have installed) as they both use TCP 9000 by default. In such case using 9001 or another port for Xdebug may solve that issue.

Comment: I am using windows 10.
I have added the xdebug log on the top. it seems everything has gone well but still it is not stopping at the breakpoint in vscode editor.

Comment: Well, log shows that VSCode successfully set 2 breakpoints in `/var/www/html/src/app/Http/Controllers/CreateUsers.php` -- on lines 16 & 27. 1) Do those lines got actually executed here? 2) The log also says that the debug session was initiated for `fileuri="dbgp://stdin"` ... which I'm not sure what this is (never seen in my setup .. as it usually has an actual file name here e.g. `fileuri="file:///app/web/info.php"`) .. and my best guess it could be some interactive shell or something.

Comment: What script you debug? Please create some standalone simple script (e.g. every instruction on a new line: `<?php $a = 1; $b = 3; $c = $a + $b; echo $c;`) and try debug it instead? Do you have different info in Xdebug log now?

Comment: The lines at CreateUsers.php gets executed. the issue is that the the control does not stop at the breakpoints. The debug console in vscode editor shows all actions happening.  
i am debugging php if you are asking that. sometime it seems that it may be caused by the wrong path mappings so I tried different path mappings but still no success.